# Convert Lambda expression in OrderBy Predicate from C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, predicate

I've got the following to sort entities by their job position. The desired order ist defined in another array. In C# this code works:

```
IEnumerable<CreditObject> query = credits.OrderBy(x =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        if (x.Job == list[i])
            return i;
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Job not within List");
});
```

However I will have to convert this to VB.net. I read the equivalent would be something like the following:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of CreditObject) = credits.OrderBy(Function(x) 

    For j As Integer = 0 To templ.Length - 1
        If x.Job = templ(j) Then
            Return j
        End If
    Next

End Function)
```

This does not compile, gives me "Expression expected" right after the `Function(x)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of VB.NET are you using ? VB 9 doesn't supports lambda expressions with multiple statements

Comment: Ok, I assume VB 2008 is version 9, so that might be the issue. Thanks! What would be an alternative? Some form of delegate to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you make that into a bonafide method:

```
public int GetCreditObjectPosition(CreditObject x, List<int> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {
        if (x.Job == list[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Job not within List");
}
```

Then, you just say:

```
IEnumerable<CreditObject> query =
    credits.OrderBy(x => GetCreditObjectPosition(x, list));
```

That's easy enough to convert to VB.

Next, you rewrite `GetCreditObjectPosition` for massive performance improvements:

```
public int GetCreditObjectPosition(CreditObject x, List<int> list) {
    var jobDictionary = 
        list.Select((job, index) => new { Job = job, Index = Index } )
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Job, item => item.Index);
    int position;
    if(!jobDictionary.TryGetValue(x.Job, out position)) {
        throw new Exception("Job not within List");
    }
    return position;
}
```